# Creating users with groups in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, users, group

Typically when I create a new user in CentOS / Redhat with the command:

```
useradd user
```

The permissions that it is assigned to the user typically works fine. I believe everything is restricted to its home directory.

I would like to accomplish a similar thing with Ubuntu Server. I am using the following SSH command to create the user:

```
useradd -n -M -s $shell -g $group -d "/home/$homedir" "$uname" -p "$passwd"
```

What group should I assign which would be similar to the CentOS equivalent or would I have to create a new group? If I were to create a new group what would those specific permissions be to mimic it?

Comment: When you create a user in Ubuntu, permissions also work fine. But maybe you have some particular requirement that CentOS meets by default but Ubuntu doesn't. What is that requirement? What do you mean by “everything is restricted to its home directory”? What are the permissions that you care about? How does this relate to groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu you should be using `adduser` instead of `useradd` (see `man useradd`).
The Ubuntu `useradd` has e.g. no `-n` option.

`adduser` creates a new group user, with the users name, as the default group:

```
adduser --no-create-home --home "/home/$homedir" "$uname"
```

You will be prompted for a password and [GECOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) info by the program. If prompting is not what you want you can do¹:

```
adduser --no-create-home --home "/home/$homedir" --disabled-password --gecos "$realname" "$uname" ; usermod -p "$passwd" "$uname"
```

The password needs to be the result of `crypt()` (man 3 crypt) and can be generated on the commandline using:

```
passwd=$(mkpasswd -m sha-512 plaintextpassword  mysalt78)
```

(the salt needs to be 8-16 characters long).

¹ <sub>While experimenting use `userdel "$uname"` to remove an account from `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, and `/etc/group` in one go.</sub>

Comment: Is there a way to include the password in the command for "adduser"?

Comment: @user3024130 `useradd` has no such option. I extended the answer with a two command, no prompt version.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I've run the command "adduser --home "/home/edgar" --disabled-password --gecos "edgar" "edgar" ; usermod -p "edgar" "edgar" but it doesn't look like its passing through the password properly. When removing the --disabled-password flag it will prompt the user for password input but will work. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3024130 as with `useradd -p` with `usermod -p` you have to provided a pre-hashed password, see update.